# best server/hosting for mysql/php with ability to scale for iphone app

Tags: iphone, web-services

I am working on an iPhone app for which I built a web service using PHP/MySQL. The app has potential for scaling, though it might also not so popular, but I want to be ready in case it scales. I want to make sure that my server can support if numbers of users exceeds let's say 100.000. The data will be mostly text, maybe some small to medium images.

Does anyone have recommendations for something that's optimum in price, and allows you to increase bandwith/storage as you need to by charging more? Since I don't know if the app will grow I don't want to make a big investment upfront, and would rather pay more as the bandwidth and storage needs increase.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Amazon server would be a good choice: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

Answer (score 0):

Amazon and GoDaddy are both really good fit from my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I use Bluehost. They have a great plan and we are running multiple apps APNS (push notifications) from the 1 account.

http://bluehost.com